# Is there a "proper" way to keep a content provider implementation seperate from it's users?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a custom `ContentProvider` class, which I originally developed in the same project file with the application using it. However since this application is intended to be only one of many users of the `ContentProvider`, I want to split it in a different project. The code is being developed on the Android PDK, but future clients might be developed on the SDK (on a custom SDK, or SDK plugin, etc).

The problem I'm facing, is about the constants in the `ContentProvider` class, e.g. CONTENT_URI, column names and as well some constants which are used to interpret the values returned from queries. These of course cannot be accessed from another project. It seems to me I have 3 options at this point:

1) Ignore the problem, and type in the values directly in the user application code. This however makes accessing the `ContentProvider` uglier. I would have to change some columns, to encode some columns with strings instead of integers, to keep the code maintainable.

2) Put the constants in a separate class, and include a full copy in applications using the `ContentProvider`. I'm not a fan of duplicating code though. Keeping a duplicate of this code in each target app, will make some things slightly more annoying to maintain.

3) Abuse the fact that I'm developing on the PDK, and expose a platform library, as described in `vendor/sample/frameworks/PlatformLibrary`. However, platform libraries don't have a manifest file, which if my understanding is correct means that I can't include a `ContentProvider`. This means I would need one "normal" project for the `ContactProvider`, and a separate one just to expose the class with the constant values. This feels so much wrong.

The answer at [Class structure for a ContentProvider having multiple sub tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277202/class-structure-for-a-contentprovider-having-multiple-sub-tables) seems to imply option (1), which probably looks like the best option right now.

However, maybe I have missed another, neat & tidy, way to do this? Keeping in mind that I am developing on the PDK, I would certainly like my `ContentProvider` to be usable in the same manner as stock Google providers.

Answer (score 3):

You probably already have at least one class/interface that defines the "contract" of your `ContentProvider` using static constants for column names, a content URI, etc.

If you put this into its own Android SDK library project (just for the Android classes to be on the build/classpath), you can then use this library from your actual SDK/PDK application's `ContentProvider` and also distribute it as `myapp-api.jar` JAR for others to use.

This way you get the best of both worlds: No outdated code (because your `ContentProvider` depends on it) and other people can use nice constants for URIs and column names.

For an example of a contract class, see [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).